# PHP If with or, then do something, reference specific true clause

Tags: php, if-statement

**How do I replace "TRUE vars" with whichever variable is actually true?**

For example:

```
<?php
    $varONE = "I am not empty";
    unset($varTWO);
    unset($varTHREE);

    if(empty($varONE) || empty($varTWO) || empty($varTHREE)) {
        echo TRUE_ONLY . "vars are empty"
    }

    //to show a working snippet of code to provide the desired results:
    if(empty($varONE)) { 
        echo "varONE is empty"; 
    }
    if(empty($varTWO)) { 
       echo "varTWO is empty"; 
    }
    if(empty($varTHREE)) { 
       echo "varTHREE is empty"; 
    }
?>
```

So the result would tell me that specifically varTWO and varTHREE are empty.
Ultimately, the goal is to check an entire forms worth of input, make sure that all 12 inputs have some value input.

Comment: There's no question here

Comment: `empty($varONE || $varTWO || $varTHREE)` will first evaluate `$v1 || $v2 || $v3`, then check if the final value is empty. It will behave in a different way than you'd expect. If any of those values is evaluated as `true`, the whole condition is `true` -since you are using `||`-, making it `empty(true)`, so it will actually enter the if...

Comment: Some clarification on my previous comment: [https://eval.in/614122](https://eval.in/614122)

Comment: @JohnConde, I've rephrased and clarified the question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

The [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) should only be passed one variable.

```
if(empty($varONE) || empty($varTWO) || empty($varTHREE)) {
  echo "TRUE vars are empty"
 }
```

Alternatively [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) can take multiple variables.

```
if(isset($varONE, $varTWO, $varTHREE)) {
  echo "TRUE vars are empty"
 }
```

> If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification  on using empty() and isset(), but I mean for the part, "TRUE vars" to be printed as whichever variable is actually true.